# Can I operate in AM mode using an Alpha 78 amplifier?

Tags: amplifier, am

I don't have any experience with amplifiers. I bought my first one last year, a used Alpha 78. I cannot find anywhere where it explicitly states that you can use the Alpha 78 in AM mode. I suspect it's fine, but each tube is nearly as expensive as the amplifier itself, so if anyone can tell me for certain that this is fine, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

The device calls itself a "HF linear amplifier". That "linear" means it's designed to amplify signals whose amplitude change, proportionally. That's exactly what AM is.

The manual, which you can download from the [vendor](https://www.alpharfsystems.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Alpha_78_Operating_and_Technical_Manual.pdf) also speaks of SSB and voice bands multiple times. So, yeah, this should be fine for AM.

> suspect it's fine, but each tube is nearly as expensive as the amplifier itself

Don't start with maximum input, but slowly tank up input powers.

I'll be brutally honest: this is a technically obsolete, if impressive in its output power, piece of hardware. It might take quite a bit of adjustments to make it run as smoothly as it did, foureand a half decades ago (or it might run great out of the box. Component aging is a strange process). It might be a good idea to do initial bring-up into a dummy load instead of an antenna, as over- or underdriving plate voltage will reduce the linearity of the gain stage and hence lead to harmonics that you might not expose your neighborhood to.

Comment: It's old enough to be rated on "plate input power", as that's what the US legal limit was based on long ago. You have to multiply by the efficiency (guesstimate 60%) to get output PEP, as commonly used today. And then it's not especialy impressive.

Comment: @hobbs-KC2G the US has the most creative ways limiting amateur operations (but yay, the bit rate limits are going away!); anyways, does that mean I'm misreading the manual and this thing does much less a kilowatt in output pep with SSB?

Comment: Around a kilowatt, SSB, and around 600W CW. Plus or minus, because efficiency can vary with the load.

Comment: The reason it used to be regulated that way is because you could easily read input power off of the same exact panel meters you needed for tuning anyway. Sampling output power is more difficut and expensive. So they were being nice to the homebuilders in particuar.

Comment: @hobbs-KC2G that's indeed very nice from a home-builder point of view; then again,  it's extremely scary to me that someone building a 1kW transmitter was not required to actually be able to measure or limit output. I think of it this way: every regulation I have for using the spectrum was made so that many more people can use this shared resource together with me. A regulation that's transmit device architecture specific instead of guaranteeing spectrum sharing is, from my private point of view, counter-productive for the goal of fair access!

Comment: Better a limit that most people respect than one that gets ignored. If someone could get a legal extra dB by building a higher-efficiency amp (while respecting the limits on harmonics, etc.), they deserve it. Even today, EIRP isn't limited on most bands, so the guy with 1500W and stacked yagis is free to be 10dB louder than the guy with 1500W into a dipole.

Comment: Well, I come from a world were spectrum usage rules are enforced, with lawyers and fines, and people in trucks with measurement equipment. The idea that "someone can build a stronger transmitter, let them have the airwaves" is … very foreign to me. I'd always go with: quite the contrary. I would want operators of communications equipment to emit the least possible power to achieve their intended application, and I would want to reward that. The objective of a spectrum assignment can't be to allow as many transmitters as possible to shout at maximum power at each other, but to maximize the(1/2)

Comment: …whole-band *usefulness* of the band – and it's not hard to see that the whole-band usefulness very quickly drops when there's misbehaving, overly strong transmitters in it! In two ways one can illustrate that: 1. Interest of the singular ego vs benefit of the group: One guy has a 10% higher PEP at the cost of 99% of operators having his overdrive-caused harmonics all over their bands. 2. Cocktail party problem: when the background interference level from a hundred strong stations is high, you have to increase TX power to get through, raising interference for the others; a vicious circle (2/2)

Comment: I know I can sound like a bit of a broken record on this, but it is very much in the amateur radio community's own interests to rather push down on single-user loudness for the benefit for mass accessibility and usefulness of the spectrum. It's a worldwide, political battle to keep the spectrum assigned as it is. And that's for a good reason – for comparison: Say I was a commercial entity offering RF-based notifications for when you get a parcel delivered, in a single small city in Germany, say, 60,000 people. All I need for that would be a spectrum allocation at 144 MHz, 1 MHz wide.

Comment: Sadly, that makes my business impossible, because, well, that band belongs to the amateur radio assignments. So, I lobby, and explain that in the whole of Germany, there's fewer people benefitting from amateur radio than there are people benefitting from my parcel notification system in that one town, and that I plan to server larger cities in a very short time. I start to lobby. I get backpressure from politics that stresses this is a culturally important hobby (this is a *very* limited-lifetime argument, by the way, at current age structures of amateur radio organizations); I concur that

Comment: it might be important, but is it more important that old people with a badly regulated and grandfathered-in >> 1000 € rig can ragchew using a century-obsolete mode (SSB) with someone in a remote location, when they could do voice over internet, and leave the actual radio usage to people who use little power and could coexist with me? After a couple years, public pressure to reassign bands to infrastructure-relevant users instead of amateur radio wins. That's the thing with privileges to use the spectrum – they're granted for as long as politics is convinced it's worth that.

Comment: And we're not talking small numbers there. UMTS saw the first spectrum auctions beyond billion dollar revenues for the auctioning state authority. 4G, 5G, all the same, but now phones can go into much higher and much lower bands than the ole UMTS and GSM phones could, *exactly because* the spectrum is so sparse that you need to take the small bands that become available due to shutting down old and little-public-benefit are sprinkled so far apart. Stronger regulation of amateur radio to the detriment to the single strong emitter is in the core interest of the community!